# Try to intercept calling any function from rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, interceptor

What i need is to intercept any function that is called from rootsope or any child scope.
So the thing is that i need to track all kind of stuff on my app and send that data to external analytic service.
So in pseudo code what i need is this:

> > $rootScope.watch($rootScope, function(event) { 
> >     analytics(event.name, event.params);
> >     event.run(); // so just continue what was about to happen...
> >     });

Hope this helps in understanding what i need.
I can not seem to catch(intercept) any of the functions.

Comment: By the wat i know that this will not work as written... I need something like interceptor for $http - but on different obj

Comment: Don't think this is possible.  When you call a function on your scope you are calling a javascript function.  You'd have to write your own proxy function maybe and call that *everywhere*, i.e. `proxy(myfunc, arg1, arg2, arg3)` instead of calling `myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.

Comment: Yes, it is not. and the thing with proxy is ugly as hell. So i dropped this idea. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was an interesting idea so I went ahead and wrote something ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/nbvRQ/1/)):

```
// global stats
var stats = {};

// function that will be called and will update stats with timing
function collectStats(f) {
    var s = stats[f.toString()];
    if (s === undefined) {
        s = { name: f.name, count: 0, time: 0 };
        stats[f.toString()] = s;
    }
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    var start = performance.now();
    var result = f.apply(this, args);
    var ms = performance.now() - start;
    s.count++;
    s.time += ms;
    return result;
}

// proxy returns a function that can be called like the original
// but that actually calls collectStats() with the function as
// an argument
function proxy(f) {
    return collectStats.bind(null, f);
}
```

You can call like so:

```
// function to slowly square a number
function squared(a) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < a; j++) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// proxy for the function that will collect timings
var f = proxy(squared);

// anonymous proxy for an identical function
var f2 = proxy(function(b) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
});

var totals = [0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 9000; i < 9005; i++) {
    totals[0] += f(i);
    totals[1] += f2(i);

    // call with inline function
    totals[2] += proxy(function(a) { return a * a; })(i);
}
```